# How to imagine the mathematical expression in the waveguide?

Tags: wave, propagation, waveguide

Below we see an example expression for the E-field. It has three components:

1. polarization of the field
2. propagation direction
3. standing wave pattern

In the photo below of the field "L" has standing wave pattern, "H" is polarisation.
So "W" is the direction of propagation of the wave?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The diagram doesn't match the equation. The equation is for a TE mode, while the diagram is for a TM mode.

Comment: Furthermore, a mode with three subscripts is probably a cavity mode, not a waveguide mode. So your title doesn't match the diagram either.

Comment: yeah, this really reads like ron, you're trying to combine images and texts from different places. Having had a hard time when I started to learn for my Microwave Engineering course, too: Stick to exactly **one** book and learn its notation (for me, that book was Pozar's *Microwave Engineering*. Personally, I don't like it, but I've not found a better book yet). Trying to combine different sources inevitably leads to tears if you're not yet experienced.

Comment: Hello The photon,In microstrip patch antenna how the TM01 looks formulated and where visually it represented in the Patch antenna.
Could you please show me?
Thanks.